# Elementary algebraic question

Tags: education

$$\frac{q^{n+1}-1+q^{n+1}(q-1)}{q-1}=\frac{q^{(n+1)+1}-1}{q-1}$$ I don't understand this step above, how can I get the right sight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{q^{n+1}-1+q^{n+1}(q-1)}{q-1}=\frac{q^{n+1}-1+q^{(n+1)+1}-q^{n+1}}{q-1}$$ Then it equals the RHS, as the term $q^{n+1}$ cancels.

Answer (score 1):

Right-hand side seems to be $q^{(n+1)+1}-1$.

Comment: Yeah a -1 is missing.

Comment: could eventually somebody text why is the calculation above correct? I'm not able to see it and it's frustrating me a lot.